# My Thinkpad X1 2015 freezes randomly. How do I diagnose the issue?

Tags: kernel, lenovo, freeze, thinkpad, 15.10

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2015 (20BSCTO1WW). Intel i5-5300U processor, 14" FHD Screen, 8GB RAM, 128GB SSD.

I'm running Wily (15.10.) I installed Wily on this machine while it was still in beta. Been keeping it updated.

The system locks up hard, seemingly at random. I've configured/tested Magic SysRq combinations, but they don't work when the system locks, and I can't switch to a terminal.

I'm not eager to do a fresh install, but can't seem to diagnose the issue.

I'm mostly looking for other diagnostic methods: the kernel goes unresponsive (doesn't panic, just freezes,) and none of the logs are showing any common thread. It happens 1-4 times per day in normal use. Seems to be related to input (ie- I've never had it happen while I wasn't directly using the machine.)

Any idea what I can try?

**EDIT 2015-11-21 @ 1:00pm EST**: The machine does not recover from the freeze.

**EDIT 2016-02-12 @ 1:30pm EST**: The issue was kernel-related. I upgraded from the 15.10 stock 4.2 kernel to one of the mainline kernels (in my case, I'm using http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-next/) and it has been running flawlessly since.

Comment: May I know your kernel version?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that I posted it.
This was an issue with the 4.2 kernel in 15.10. I upgraded to 4.3 and 4.4 through the mainline kernel repos and have had zero problems since.

Comment: Great, that solves the problem then. In my case too, when I updated to 4.5 mainline kernel problem vanished. So may I suggest you to answer your own question and to "accept" that answer? It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was kernel-related. I upgraded from the 15.10 stock 4.2 kernel to one of the mainline kernels (in my case, I'm using http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-next/) and it has been running flawlessly since.

I didn't find the root of the problem, but the kernel upgrade allowed me to get on with my life error-free.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `swap` partition?

Collect more data. Here are some ways:

If the system recovers from the freeze (not clear from above), immediately do `ls -lrt /var/log`, and inspect the most recently modified logfiles.

Write a Bash script to collect data (`date`, `uptime`, `ps -efwwwl`,`free`, ...), append it to a file, `sync`, sleep for N seconds and loop. Then run it backgrounded, at a high priority (`man nice`).

Consider running `gkrellm`, to display system performance.

Comment: I am using a swap partition. The Wily install disk set it up that way.

I just re-installed yesterday from scratch, because I figured it might have been something during the Beta2 install process that set it off.

But no, it's still doing a hard-non-recoverable freeze. It took about 20 hours before the first one happened. I went to move my mouse and it didn't want to move.

I'm going to look into building a cronjob that writes out details. Also going to look into tweaking the synaptic settings some more. I'm convinced it's an input issue (but who knows, I could be wrong.)